# Can iFrame Scrollbars be skinned in webkit?

Tags: html, css, iframe, webkit, scrollbars

It's pretty well known by now that you can style scrollbars using the webkit specific CSS tags (::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment, etc. ). However, I've noticed that I cannot style the scrollbars attached to iFrames.

Question: Is there a way to access and style the scrollbars on the iFrame using webkit? (Yes, I've actually got a particular scenario where I'd like to be able to do this.)

Thanks much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The iframe scrollbars are actually part of the document *inside* the iframe. As a result, you have to set the scrollbar styles in the document you are loading into the iframe, not in the document that contains the iframe.